# Loss does not reduce with an auto-encoder like setup with PyTorch v1.4

Tags: python, python-3.x, deep-learning, pytorch, recurrent-neural-network

I am new to PyTorch and have written the following code. I am using one neural network for the encoding part followed by some processing of the encoded data and then using another network for the decoding this data.

```py
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.nn.functional as F
import torch.optim as optim
from torch.optim.lr_scheduler import StepLR
import numpy as np
import itertools
import datetime


class Encoder(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Encoder, self).__init__()
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(4, 32, bias=False)
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(32, 16, bias=False)
        self.fc3 = nn.Linear(16, 7, bias=False)

    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.fc1(x)
        x = torch.tanh(x)
        x = self.fc2(x)
        x = torch.tanh(x)
        x = self.fc3(x)
        output = torch.tanh(x)
        return output


def channel(codeword, snr_db, device):
    snr_value = 10 ** (snr_db / 10)
    h_real = torch.normal(mean=0, std=1, size=(codeword.shape[0], 1)) * torch.sqrt(torch.as_tensor(1/2))
    h_imag = torch.normal(mean=0, std=1, size=(codeword.shape[0], 1)) * torch.sqrt(torch.as_tensor(1/2))
    h_real_t = h_real.repeat(1, codeword.shape[1]).to(device)
    h_imag_t = h_imag.repeat(1, codeword.shape[1]).to(device)
    noise_real = torch.normal(mean=0, std=1, size=codeword.shape) * torch.sqrt(torch.as_tensor(1/(2*snr_value)))
    noise_imag = torch.normal(mean=0, std=1, size=codeword.shape) * torch.sqrt(torch.as_tensor(1/(2*snr_value)))
    noise_real = noise_real.to(device)
    noise_imag = noise_imag.to(device)
    faded_cw_real = torch.mul(h_real_t, codeword) + noise_real
    faded_cw_imag = torch.mul(h_imag_t, codeword) + noise_imag
    return torch.cat([faded_cw_real[:, :, None], faded_cw_imag[:, :, None]], dim=2), h_real, h_imag


class Decoder(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Decoder, self).__init__()
        self.bigru = nn.GRU(input_size=7, hidden_size=200, num_layers=20, bidirectional=True)
        self.fc0 = nn.Linear(4, 1)
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(400, 4)

    def forward(self, x):
        x, states = self.bigru(x)
        output = torch.squeeze(self.fc0(torch.transpose(x, 2, 1)))
        output = torch.tanh(output)
        output = self.fc1(output)
        output = torch.tanh(output)
        # output = torch.softmax(output, dim=0)
        return output


def train(args, model1, model2, device, optimizer, epoch, snr):
    model1.train()
    model2.train()
    count = 1000
    for i in range(count):
        data = np.array([list(i) for i in itertools.product([-1, 1], repeat=4)])
        p = np.random.permutation(16)
        # p = np.random.randint(low=0, high=16, size=(16,))
        train_data = data[p]
        data_one_hot = np.eye(16)
        truth = data_one_hot[p]
        # truth = torch.as_tensor(truth).to(device).float()  # Uncomment this for BCE loss
        train_data = torch.as_tensor(train_data).float()
        train_data = train_data.to(device)
        # optimizer1.zero_grad()
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        output = model1(train_data)
        output = output.to(device)
        ch_out, h_r, h_i = channel(output, snr, device)
        h_r = torch.as_tensor(h_r[:, :, None].repeat(1, 7, 1)).to(device)
        h_i = torch.as_tensor(h_i[:, :, None].repeat(1, 7, 1)).to(device)
        dec_ip = torch.cat([ch_out, h_r, h_i], 2)
        dec_ip = torch.transpose(dec_ip, 2, 1)
        hat = model2(torch.as_tensor(dec_ip).float())
        loss_d = F.mse_loss(hat, train_data)
        # loss_d = F.binary_cross_entropy(hat, truth)
        loss_d.backward()
        optimizer.step()
        if i % 10 == 0:
            # print(f"Train epoch: {epoch}, Batch: {i}, Encoder Loss: {loss_e.item()}, SNR: {snr}")
            print(f"Train epoch: {epoch}, Batch: {i}, Decoder Loss: {loss_d.item()}, SNR: {snr}")


def main():
    epochs = 14
    learning_rate = 1
    learning_rate_step = 0.7
    no_cuda = False
    log_interval = 10
    use_cuda = not no_cuda and torch.cuda.is_available()
    device = torch.device("cuda" if use_cuda else "cpu")
    enc_model = Encoder().to(device)
    dec_model = Decoder().to(device)
    optimizer = optim.Adam(list(dec_model.parameters())+list(enc_model.parameters()), lr=learning_rate)
    scheduler = StepLR(optimizer, step_size=1, gamma=learning_rate_step)
    for epoch in range(1, epochs+1):
        snr = 20 - 20 * epoch / epochs
        train(log_interval, enc_model, dec_model, device, optimizer, epoch, snr)
        scheduler.step()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

However when I run this, the output is:

```
Train epoch: x, Batch: y, Decoder Loss: 2.0, SNR: z
```

`x`, `y` and `z` values are dependent on the iteration. The decoder loss is stuck at `2.0`. In fact, the loss starts at lesser than `2` and then gets stuck at `2.0`.

Is there something simply wrong with the code?